# SRAM hydraulic brake weak - new bike

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, sram

I bought a new gravel bike (Serious Grafix Pro) with SRAM hydraulic disc brakes.
The rear one has very weak stopping power.

I can pull the right/rear brake lever completely to the handlebar and the pads just softly touch the rotor. So I'm wondering if I can just e.g. tighten a screw to make it more sensitive.

How can I adjust it? I found many Youtube videos, but none I needed.

Sorry for my lame question, not particularly strong for (not only) bike mechanics.

Thanks

Comment: Is the brake slipping or is it just easier to bottom out the rear brake lever than the front. You're not giving us much to go off.

Comment: I can pull the right/rear brake lever completely to the handlebar and the pads just softly touch the rotor. So I'm wondering if I can just e.g. tighten a screw to make it more sensitive.

Comment: @RadekS Sounds like they need a bleed. Is there fluid leaking from anywhere on the rear brake/brake line/caliper?

Comment: @PhilipGibbons, I will check it in an hour, but didn't notice any leaking yesterday when I got it. Is it normal for a new bike? My MTB that was also sent to me has brakes just strong, rock solid out-of-the-box (literary).

Comment: @RadekS Have you ever bled a hydraulic brake before? If not, I'd suggest bringing it to a bike shop. It's pretty easy to do but also pretty easy to mess up and/or contaminate your rotor/pads while doing it.

Comment: If you can squeeze the brake lever all the way to the handlebar, then something is definitely wrong. This rule applies to all brakes, not just hydraulics. Since this is a new bike, you should take it back to the shop and have them fix it.

Comment: Thanks all guys, I contacted the seller yesterday (as I bought the bike online) and they told me to take it to a local shop to re-bleed the brake, they will pay for the service. This morning they told me in the shop that it really looks there is some air in the system.

Comment: It's not at all unusual for a bike that has been shipped to get air in the hydraulic brakes, as the bike may be placed on its end or upside-down at times, and this allows air to enter.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need a brake bleed, as mentioned in the comments.  If there is air in a hydraulic system, the brake levers feel "spongy", or may not actuate the brake enough at all, which is what this sounds like.  Any time you can squeeze a brake lever all the way to the grip, that's a dangerously underpowered brake.  Brake bleeding is a process, and while you can do it yourself, it's usually recommended to take it to a shop, as it is easy to mess up, and messing up on a brake bleed can mean you ruin pads/hoses/calipers/levers, and can get costly.